# Material Design UI

Tags: android, jquery, user-interface

I came across this Term called "**Material Design"** in android. This refers to redesign of existing android UI.

Apart from attractive colors and various UI panels. Basically what is difference between Material Design  from normal design?

How Material Design is different from normal design? I need basic principles to follow in Material Design UI.

Comment: Read the (very long) material provided by Google.

Comment: http://www.google.com/design/

Answer (score 2):

Material design as the Google guidelines is not just the design for a particular platform, It is a visual language which can be used on every platform whether it is Smartphone, tablets, PCs, TVs etc. without making any changes.

It follows three principles:
**1.** Material is a metaphor i.e. sense of depth by using 'material' principles, like pieces of paper.
**2.** Bold, Graphic, Intentional i.e. Aesthetic typography, color etc.
**3.** Motion provides meaning i.e.interaction with object can defined by their motion.

So, its not just another extension to flat design.

While Normal design can consist flat design as Apple uses, It is the principle that make changes.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for SOF.

Answer (score 1):

The point of Material Design is that if you're the kind of person who doesn't understand the point of Material Design, then you should definitely use it.

Unlike Apple's Human Interface Guidelines, or the complex interplay of principles, patterns, and psychology that one learns in Design school, Material Design is a *specification*.

It tells you exactly what to do when and where, without letting you make design mistakes. If you're not the world's best UX Designer, it's probably better that you blindly follow the Material Design spec, and not make any design decisions yourself. Your users will thank you.

And in the process of reading, understanding, and applying the spec, you'll become a better designer.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, material design is highly practiced.

The main objective of bringing out **Material Design is to provide a platform that is tactile for the users and open doors of creativity for designers.** The design ideas of early days were totally based on ink and paper but Material Design drives the ideas to a new level thus by making it magical.

**Material seems more realistic with surfaces and edges and incorporates boundless possibilities of introducing advanced and flexible designs.**

There is a focus on using light and movement and the fundamental elements and priority is given to the print-based design like use of typography, grid space etc.Focus is on user functionality and design lays stress on primary user focus points.

Regards

Oodles Studio