# Getting started with material-ui

Tags: node.js, web, reactjs, material-ui

Seems to me the well-kept secret is the material-ui, a web framework that uses Google's [Material Design UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561514/material-design-ui), plus React. I think it is a fantastic combination, and the future. However, it is also a well well-kept secret on how to use it. The Getting started guide at http://material-ui.com/#/get-started is not for normal Joe, but only for a tiny fraction of people that might understand it. Moreover, the questions here, like [How to use material-ui framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195787/how-to-use-material-ui-framework), [material ui Installation configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045003/material-ui-installation-configure), have never been answered.

I managed to get material-ui installed,

```
  $ npm install material-ui
  react-tap-event-plugin@0.1.6 node_modules/react-tap-event-plugin

  react@0.13.2 node_modules/react
   envify@3.4.0 (through@2.3.7, jstransform@10.1.0)

  material-ui@0.7.4 node_modules/material-ui
   classnames@1.2.1
   react-draggable2@0.5.1

  $ ls -d1 node_modules/*
  node_modules/material-ui
  node_modules/react
  node_modules/react-tap-event-plugin
```

but what's next?

- Should I move them under my `/var/www/`? Or start nodejs, or...?
- How can I see a simple demo that show everything is working?

All in all, as someone who knows only http servers and static html pages, what's the simplest way for me to see it is working with my existing web server in my own environment?

Thanks

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:        14.10
Codename:       utopic

$ uname -srmv
Linux 3.16.0-34-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 18:02:58 UTC 2015 x86_64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start an example just follow the instructions from [github](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/example).

```
cd <project folder>/material-ui/example
npm install
npm start
```

and open a http://localhost:8000/ in your browser.

Comment: The `npm install material-ui` didn't install that `example` folder. So I downloaded one myself. However, should I do the above `npm install` within my downloaded folder, or should I move it down to within the `node_modules/material-ui` folder that `npm install material-ui` created then run `npm install`? Thx

Comment: Yes, you need to run npm install in downloaded folder. It's grab the requirements to start a web-server.

Comment: May be worth adding that there is a bug with older version obtained by **npm install material-ui**. I had to downloaded the most recent material-ui from the Github page to fix **issue #1117**: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui

Comment: that github link is broken